# Close only one window in Emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

In vim, buffer can be split horizontally or vertically by `:sp` or `:vsp`. And a buffer can be closed by `:q`.

Likewise in emacs, window can be split horizontally by `C-x 2`, and vertically by `C-x 3`.
And close all other window by `C-x 1`.

But, how can I close only one window, like `:q` in vim?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try `C-x 0`, `delete-window`. This is what `C-h k` describes:

```
(delete-window &optional WINDOW)

Remove WINDOW from its frame.
WINDOW defaults to the selected window.  Return nil.
Signal an error when WINDOW is the only window on its frame.
```

Answer (score 8):

There is `delete-window` which is binded to `C-x 0` by default.

Answer (score 7):

You can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> to close current window, which is the default binding for `delete-window`